# C: Signal sending to children causes infinity loop

Tags: c, process, signals, fork, posix

I've got following problem with my code. It(children) should start counting from 0 when child process receives SIGHUP (works fine), but when parent process gets signal hup it should make all children  count from 0 again, but when signal is sent then something like infinity loop happens and on_hup function for parent is called all time and doesn''t stop :( Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include "err.h"
#define NR_PROC 3

pid_t pid;
int a;
int pids[3];

void on_hup(int sig){    
    int i;
    if(pid!=0)           
        kill(0,SIGHUP);
    else    
        a=0;
}

void pierwsze(){
    for (;a<10000;a++){
        printf("%d: %d PID: %d \n",getpid(),a,pid);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);
} 

}

struct sigaction init(){
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t block_mask;
    sigemptyset (&block_mask);
    sa.sa_mask = block_mask;
    sa.sa_flags=0;
    sa.sa_handler=on_hup;
    return sa;
}

int main(){
int i;
a=0;
struct sigaction setup_action = init();
sigaction(SIGHUP,&setup_action,0);

for(i=0;i<NR_PROC;i++){
    switch(pid = fork()){
      case -1:
        fprintf(stderr,"Error w fork \n");
      case 0:
        pids[i]=getpid();
        pierwsze();
        return 0;
      default:
        printf("I am parent My PID = %d\n",getpid());
        printf("fork = %d\n",pid);
    }
}
while(1){}
wait(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your intent was for `pids` to contain the process ids of all the child processes, but variables are not not shared between different processes, so when the child sets `pids[i]=getpid()`, the parent process's `pids` array will not be changed.

Comment: Ops my bad but still changed pids[i] to 0 and still doesn't work as it was supossed to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array `pids` cannot be shared between the parent and child.

So instead of trying to put the pid into the array from the context of the child, you can insert it from the parent's context:

Code will look like:

```
case 0:
    pierwsze();
    return 0;
default:
    pids[i] = pid;
    printf("I am parent My PID = %d\n",getpid());
    printf("fork = %d\n",pid);
```